# How can I create topic with kafka-php programming library?

Tags: php, apache-kafka

I want create a topic with kafka-php programming library.

https://github.com/weiboad/kafka-php

How can I do?

If topic doesn't exist in kafka server, executing this code, it doesn't work. It doesn't insert 10 messages "test1....message." because topic isn't create.

```
date_default_timezone_set('PRC');
// Create the logger
$logger = new Logger('my_logger');
// Now add some handlers
$logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(DIR . '/app.log', Logger::DEBUG));

$config = \Kafka\ProducerConfig::getInstance();
$config->setMetadataRefreshIntervalMs(10000);
$config->setMetadataBrokerList('127.0.0.1:9092');
$config->setBrokerVersion('1.0.0');
$config->setRequiredAck(1);
$config->setIsAsyn(false);
$config->setProduceInterval(500);
$producer = new \Kafka\Producer();
$producer->setLogger($logger);

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
$result = $producer->send([
[
'topic' => 'test1',
'value' => 'test1....message.',
'key' => ''
]
]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is support for this in the available PHP libraries.

The functionality is implemented in the Admin API in the Java client library for Kafka which will enable you to [create a topic](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#createTopics-java.util.Collection-org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.CreateTopicsOptions-). I found [this github issue](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-rdkafka/issues/215) against another PHP Kafka client regarding implementing the Admin API but it has not been done.

Comment: I couldn't install https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-rdkafka. I have install librdkafka e then manually installing the extension. Extension go to /usr/lib/php/20170718 but I need extension in folder /usr/lib/php/20190902. How can compile extension for /usr/lib/php/20190902?

Comment: @NicolaPaganotti It'd be best to ask questions about that specific library in the Github issues there.

Comment: I could create topic in kafka from php calling a shell script if the library doesn't support to create topic.